# how to merge release changes into master using pull requests

Tags: git, process, pull-request

We got following setup for our pull requests. We have one main branch which is the master. For features we create Feature Branches and for bugs we create Bug fix branches which means we branch from the the master or release version in which it needs to be fixed in. Each pull request gets created for the branch it was created from which is easy and straight forward. But now I struggle a little with bug fixes.

In the case of a bug fix the PR is created for the release branch and is merged. So good so far but now the bug is fixed in the release. That's where my problem starts. How do I get the bugfix into the master now without merging it manually?

1. Is it possible to use any pull request mechanism?
2. What happens in case of conflicts?
3. Can apply a automated fix to solve this issue?

Comment: You mention a `master` branch in the first paragraph, and a `release` branch in the second. Can you explain how these branches are related ?

Comment: In our setup it's not possible to merge stuff to the master or release branch without a pull request. In case of a bug fix we merge the change into the release branch but how do we get the changes into the master branch afterwards?

Comment: Ok. How different are `master` and `release` ? Is `release` always behind `master` ? `master` behind `release` ? What gets merged into `master` and `release` ? Maybe draw a sketch of your branches in your question ?

Comment: GolezTrol explained it very well in his comment. You might wanna read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to keep the release branches separate. In that case you need to make the same (or similar) fix in master too.

To do that in a nice-ish way, you can make a new bug branch of master, and cherry pick the commits from the release branch. That will basically give you a copy of those commits in the other branch.

Comment: I don't want to keep them separate. It's more a permission issue. Nobody can merge into the release or master branch without a pull request. I could overrule that but so I need to do all the merges which I want to avoid

Comment: I don't understand how your branching model works. I thought that master is the 'ongoing' work branch, in which features are merged (using PR). At some point you label something to be release, and for that you have a release branch, which can get bug fixes. I imagined you want to keep the release branches separate from master, so a release will always stand on its own, with the additional fixes/patches you do for it. In that case, you need to make the change in two places, and my remark about cherry picking applies.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create a pull request from release to master, to get the fix into master as well, but that is likely to fail because the release branch is behind master. You can't update it either, because then you would pull all the new additions into a previous release. I think what you could do is make a separate branch (like 'Release1.3_to_master'), make sure it's up to date with master, pull in the changes from Release, resolve any merge conflicts, and make a PR from that branch to master.

Comment: This should work but it quite complicated. Are there any tools which automate this process?

Comment: For solving merge conflicts, no. But the steps themselves can be scripted.

Comment: It's not _that_ complicated by the way. 1. Branch from Release, 2. Bring up to date with master *) 3. Resolve any merge conflicts. 4. Make a PR from branch to master. *) Just note, you can either merge or rebase that branch, but rebase gives you copies of the commits again, basically the same end result as with the cherry picking. It gives a cleaner history, though, and otherwise you will forever see the merges from Release back into master, which wouldn't have my preference. But that's up to you, of course.